# pipenv location path error (pulls me into different directories)

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I am having a problem with launching to heroku via my virtual enviorment and i think it is because my virtual enviorment is set up incorrect.

In order to test that i have set it up correctly this is what i have done.

1. uninstalled pipenv by `pip3 uninstall pipenv`
2. reinstalled by `pip3 install pipenv`
3. Cd to desktop and made a directory call called "django2"
4. cd into "django2"
5. tried to install django in "django2" by `pipenv install django`
6. Opened the pipenv shell by doing `pipenv shell`

No when i opened the pipenv shell in step 7 i thought i would see (`django2) $` in my terminal. Instead i am getting pulled back to my user profile seeing `(my name) $`
what is the story here?
because in order to launch multiple projects to heroku i will need  multiple "pipfles" and "piplock" files. along with each project having its own "Procfile".
but the way it seems to currently be set up is that i only have one "pipfles" and "piplock" file located in my user account.

Answer (score 1):

You may set Custom Virtual Environment Location,

> "you can also have Pipenv stick the virtualenv in project/.venv by setting the PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT environment variable"

https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv/#custom-virtual-environment-location

add a new environment variable named PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT, and set it to 'true',

save, restart, cd into your project folder and run

`pipenv install django`,

when you run `pipenv shell`, the .venv inside your project is up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a `Pipfile` in your home directory.

By default, pipenv search up to 3 parent directories for the Pipfile.

This can be changed with [PIPENV_MAX_DEPTH](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv.environments.PIPENV_MAX_DEPTH)